# Copy files - format drive - paste files back (Will the files/software installation be affected?)

Tags: windows, formatting

**Question:** If a Windows user copies all the files from a drive, saves it elsewhere, formats the drive & pastes the files back. will it effect any programs that were copied i.e `program files` folder?

**Example:** I have X software installed on `E:` drive, after copying it and formatting the drive then pasting the files back, will Windows somehow won't recognize the installation or mark the existence of software X as corrupt?

**My case:** I am going to install ubuntu to my `E:`drive, but I want to let it format the drive but without messing up with my current programs' installation on that file so I am planing to copy my files on external hard drive then paste it back. (And no, the drive I will install on is not the one I have Windows on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it [a]ffect any programs that were copied i.e program files folder?

I expect potential troubles, depending on how this is done.

**An old example:**
Well, this question is tagged "Windows", and I expect no troubles if you're using Windows 3.1, as long as the system can still boot DOS (which a simple "SYS C:") is likely to fix.

**Changing Times:**
However, I'm guessing you're referring to more modern versions of Microsoft Windows.  In that case, depending on exactly how you make the copy, then, yes, there's definitely potential that you're going to have massive problems.

I'm going to use the term "File Manager", as that is the term used by Windows 3.1 and Windows 10.  If you use other versions of Microsoft Windows made in between those releases, you'll likely find the software is called "Explorer" or "Windows Explorer".  Rather than being redundant each time, I'm simply using one term, so adjust (as needed) to fit whatever Windows you're using.

**WinSXS:**
If you're using a copy of Windows that is not running (e.g., you shut down Windows and boot from a CD that runs Linux and can access NTFS), you may have fewer problems.  If you're doing this from Windows while running, and simply using "File Manager" to copy all of the folder icons you find in the top-level folder, then expect pain.

The first thing that comes to mind is the C:\Windows\WinSXS folder.  This folder contains "side by side assemblies" data.  The operating system treats this folder as special.  In an effort to make DLL handling work easier/better for end users, Windows performs some special handling of this folder to be able to essentially store and use multiple versions of the same file.  This tends to work transparently behind the scenes, and work great.  Problems can arise, though, if you actually try to interact with the folder another way.

For instance, the [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) (freely downloadable program) shows you information that helps people easily see where disk space gets used.  So, WinDirStat does some standard things, like asking Windows what files are in the folder, and how big each file is.  The problem is that the C:\Windows\WinSXS\ folder is intended to be treated in a special way.  Since WinDirStat doesn't handle the C:\Windows\WinSXS as a special folder, the results end up looking confusing: The C:\Windows\WinSXS looks like it takes up a ridiculously large amount of space.

If you try to copy the data from that directory, I suspect you may encounter issues with components of Microsoft Windows like User Account Control or System File Protection.  However, even if you did manage to be given access to complete the attempt to copy, you would likely end up copying multiple versions of the same data.  The result is that your destination will not match your source.  (The destination will be bigger, and quite possibly much bigger.  You might run out of space on the destination device.)

Furthermore, even if the copy did appear to succeed, and then you copied the information back to a fresh drive, Microsoft Windows is *expecting* the C:\Windows\WinSXS directory to be handled in special ways.  So if you dumped a bunch of normal data into that directory while Microsoft Windows tries to use it, that "normal" data would not fit the expectations that Microsoft Windows has of the C:\Windows\WinSXS directory.

**Page File**
The page file is used to store data that Microsoft Windows should keep track of, but which isn't in memory.

It could be that if the page file got copied to the destination, and then Microsoft Windows wrote some more data to the original page file (perhaps while you are still copying some of the rest of the data on the drive), that data might never get copied to the destination page file.  Microsoft Windows memory management is complex and can use both RAM and an active page file.  When you copy the drive, the destination copy wouldn't contain anything that is RAM.  Since Microsoft Windows is rather complex and does some things behind the scenes, I could easily believe that some data could be lost if the new copy of Windows didn't get some of the data successfully copied over.

**thumbs.db:**
Let's say you have 3 (or more) files in a directory:

- a.jpg
- b.jpg
- thumbs.db
- y.jpg
- z.jpg

When you copy a.jpg to an empty folder, File Manager tries to handle recognized graphics in a special way.  File Manager will re-size the graphic down to a "thumbnail" size, and store the result in thumbs.db.

Then, when File Manager tries to copy the pre-existing thumbs.db file, it will see that a thumbs.db already exists in the destination directory.  File Manager may prompt you, asking about overwriting the existing file, or using the pre-existing file (which it just made).  That may be annoying, and essentially pause some of the process of copying data, preventing further automated progress until you interact with the software.

Then, after copying thumbs.db, which now has a thumbnail for any files already in the destination folder (e.g., a.jpg and b.jpg), the remaining graphics files (e.g., y.jpg and z.jpg) will have thumbnails created, modifying thumbs.db each time.  In theory, Microsoft Windows may create thumbnails in the exact same way (if the graphics haven't been modified, and the relevant part of Microsoft Windows hasn't been modified since the old thumbs.db file), but even if you do have the same bytes, your file creation time will be modified.  So, your copy won't be an exact duplicate.

**File Order**
When you write files, older operating systems would just dump the latest file in the end of a list.  This resulted in files being stored in what is called "unsorted" order.  This was common when Windows was typically dealing with FAT drives.

Now, I've read that NTFS tries to be someone intelligent by storing files in a "B Tree" to try to automatically sort files a bit.  That can provide some speed benefits in the long run, but making a perfect sort takes more time up front, so NTFS basically makes an attempt but accepts imperfection in the sorting.

File Manager may decide to copy files in a different format, like alphabetically.

**Summary/Review**
These might not be the only differences your destination may have from the source, but they are some differences that I happen to know of.  While the thumbs.db file creation time might not matter, and the file ordering probably won't matter (since many people have been known to adjust the file ordering when using Defrag), I wouldn't be bold enough to say that these things won't matter for everybody.  The way that people use Microsoft Windows is pretty customizable, so what is perfectly ignorable for one person might be highly irritating or damaging for another person.

The WinSXS issue is particularly likely to cause problems, so the simple answer is: No, a simply copy of the data is not necessarily going to result in a perfect copy that would work just as well as the original.

> My case: I am going to install ubuntu to my E:drive, but I want to let it format the drive but without messing up with my current programs' installation on that file so I am planing to copy my files on external hard drive then paste it back.

A lot of what I complained about is especially likely if you copy the drive that Windows is installed onto, and/or the page file.  If E: doesn't fit those descriptions, you may be less likely to encounter problems.  However, with the potential of "copy protection", there could potentially be some cases where differences in the E: could be noticed from software.

Some of this depends on what is on E:.  If all you had were zip files, a simple file copy would probably work okay.  You mentioned "Program Files".  Well, many programs would not have any problem.  However, I'm not saying that all programs would have no problem.  Different programs have different amounts of complexity.  For instance, some programs may have DLL file fragments stored in WinSXS, while other programs won't.  So, results can very quite a bit.

**Use an image:**
Here's a safer solution that is much more likely to work.  Use imaging software.  (Use software that creates a "bit-accurate" image, sometimes called a "forensive image".  Make such an image of the entire drive, including the "meta-data" that stores the data of the filesystem structures, like the timestamps related to the files.)  Create an image of the E:, preferably when the drive is dismounted.  Then, later, restore the image.

Ubuntu's "dd" can do this, as well as some programs for Microsoft Windows that can be downloaded.  I would expect "Clonezilla" to also be able to pull this off.

Using image software on an inactive drive is much more likely to work than to try to use Windows to just copy the files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a program such as [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) that correctly copies *all* of the files' content, including security ACLs, you should not have a problem. The one exception I can think of is if one of the files has an alternate data stream, but that's highly unlikely.

If you do this and it fails though, you're stuck, so I'd recommend using a program like CloneZilla to create an *image* of the drive. You can still do the copy method too if you're curious, but the image is guaranteed to capture everything and will save the day if the copy method fails.

Comment: CloneZilla will work even if I install ubuntu on the hard drive first after formatting & then call back old data?

Comment: I cant take the risk (have a very tight schedule) but I will definitely try this experiment on a new hard drive & share the results - Any Idea which software I should install to test the copy/paste & other methods?

Comment: [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx), which is a built in Windows command.

Comment: I'm now wondering if you're planning to install Ubuntu to your E: drive. If that's the case, then you *can't* use CloneZilla to restore the data because it saves entire volumes/drives, not individual files. In this case, Robocopy is your go-to method (although I'd *still* make a backup with CloneZilla in case things go bad and you need to start over).

Comment: Yes I was planing to install Ubuntu on my E: drive but thought I should simply get a new drive to avoid any risk but I will do a test run of robocopy as you suggested by installing some software on new drive then installing Ubuntu on it and pasting software back to see how they behave.